# I need to transfer my images from raspberyy pi to web app wirelessly .Images will captured on camera connected to r pi

Tags: image, flask, web-applications, raspberry-pi4

Hello MY project is to receive images from a raspberry pi through a web app once the receive button is clicked on the frontend and store them in a database. .Now where to upload those images once captured on camera connected to r pi and what protocol and connectivity shall I use between web app and r pi . I'll CREATE WEB APP backend using flask (a python framework). So pleasae guide me on flask backend and r pi and how do i go on with this project. Also what database will be suitable for storing of these images .In web app there will also be a part called "history" once clicked on this it will show the previously recieved images from r pi so what database will be good?

I tried creating a server on r pi and based on HTTP protocol tried transfering image and regarding web app its not ready yet as i couldn't get theidea how to proceed.Basically previously what i thought of was that  to create a server on r pi (using flask and http method)by providing url of web app on this r pi

```
import requests
import cv2

# Flask server URL
flask_server_url = 'http://your_flask_server_ip:5000/receive_image'

# Capture an image using a Raspberry Pi camera or another source
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
ret, frame = cap.read()

# Convert the image to bytes
_, img_encoded = cv2.imencode('.jpg', frame)
img_bytes = img_encoded.tobytes()

# Send the image to the Flask server
try:
    response = requests.post(flask_server_url, data=img_bytes)
    print(response.text)
except requests.RequestException as e:
    print(f'Error: {e}')

cap.release()
```

server code
This is the code i could come up with (i haven not tested this yet)